# Calculating the area of boundary

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis

Let $G=\{(x,y,z)|z>x^2+y^2 \ and \ x^2+y^2+z^2<2\}\subset \mathbb{R}^3$.

Calculate the area of the boundary: $\partial G=M$.

I don't even know how to approach this..any help?

Comment: Although you can do this in a totally elementary fashion, presumably you are supposed to compute the area of a cone and the area of a part of a sphere using surface integrals?

Comment: @TedShifrin $z>x^2 + y^2$ is paraboloid and not a cone, increasing the degree of difficulty just a little bit.

Comment: Agh, I'm being too sloppy. Apologies. Can't do the paraboloid with just geometry. Definitely need a surface integral (which then turns into a double integral). @DougM: $z=x^2+y^2$ is a paraboloid; $z>x^2+y^2$ would be called the interior of the paraboloid or some such ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boundary of the area in common have one portion that is a paraboloid, and one portion that is the surface of a sphere.

Lets convert to cylindrical coordinates.

$x = r \cos\theta\\\
y = r \sin\theta\\
z = z $

for one surface:

$x^2 + y^2 = z\\
z = r^2$

and for the other

$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 2\\
r^2 + z^2 = 2\\
z = \sqrt {2-r^2}$

$\|dS\| = \|(\frac {\partial x}{\partial \theta},\frac {\partial y}{\partial \theta},\frac {\partial z}{\partial \theta})\times(\frac {\partial x}{\partial r},\frac {\partial y}{\partial r},\frac {\partial z}{\partial r})\|$

for one surface that will be

$\|(-r\sin\theta, r\cos\theta, 0) \times (\cos\theta, \sin\theta, 2r)\| = r\sqrt {4r^2+1}\ dr\ d\theta$

and the other

$\|(-r\sin\theta, r\cos\theta, 0) \times (\cos\theta, \sin\theta, \frac {r}{\sqrt {2-r^2}})\| = \frac {2}{\sqrt {2-r^2}}$

Check my work on those... If I have that right then.

$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{1} r\sqrt {4r^2+1}+\frac {2}{\sqrt {2-r^2}}\ dr\ d\theta$

Comment: @TedShifrin didn't I.  But in my defense I did correct myself in the next sentence...anyway the offending line has been stricken from the record.  Actually, I was about 1/2 way through before I notices that it wasn't, in fact, a cone, and had to start over.